# How to get multiple views without refreshing the browser via sidebar in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

So what i was trying to do is to be able to use my admin page sidebar navigator (i.e. a side bar that has a few tabs for home, maps, user-profiles). So that say when I am on the 'home' tab and when I click on 'user-profiles' it will update the page but not refresh the browser for the new view..

I was thinking about using v-if on my vue.js views page. so that v-if i select 'user-profiles' tab then use this .vue file as the main component or container.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <Header />
    <AppBarAdmin />

    <v-layout class="main">
      <NavAdmin class="sidebar" />
      <v-flex xs12 class="display_container">
        <Dashboard class="dashboard" />
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

  </v-container>
</template>
```

so what i was thinking was being able to use a v-if statement on the `<Dashboard class="dashboard">` line so that the logic might be 'if clicked on Dashboard' then display this vue file

Comment: Use `vue-router` instead ([link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript)) so you can juggle the component on a per route basis.